# How to mock Laravel model for a test of a class?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a class like this:

```php
<?php 
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductSearcher
{
    public function getPrintedProducts( $releasedOnly = true ) {
        $products = Product::with('productVersion','productVersion.tag')
                      ->where('printed', 1);
        if ($releasedOnly)
            $products->where('released', 1);
        $products = $products->get();
        return $products;
    }
}
```

In my testing, I write

```php
// ... some other testing ...
public function testChossingCorrectingProductFromProductVersionIds()
{
    $productSearcher= new ProductSearcher;

    $productMock = \Mockery::mock( 'App\Models\Product' );
    $productMock->shouldReceive( 'with->where->where->get' )->andReturn( [] );

    $this->assertEmpty( $productSearcher->getPrintedProducts( true ) );
}
// ... some other testing ...
```

I run the test but get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare Mockery_1_App_Models_Product::mockery_init()
```

May I ask what have I done wrong? Or what is the proper way to test this function? (It is a unit test that should not be too heavy, so connecting to a testing database is not an option)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more that what are you trying to test? are you trying to test that the table is empty or the function is working correctly or what?

Comment: @cytsunny I have updated my answer, let me know if that is better now and solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a [factory](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories) to "mock" models, you don't mock core classes, you just fake them. You have to create a model or models with the data you should expect to have at that moment.

For you to correctly test your code, you should have code like this:

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\ProductVersion;
use App\Models\Tag;
use App\ProductSearcher;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ProductSearcherTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_correct_products_get_returned_when_released_only_is_true(): void
    {
        $firstProduct = Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 1,
                'released' => 1,
            ]);

        $secondProduct = Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 1,
                'released' => 1,
            ]);

        Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 1,
                'released' => 0,
            ]);

        Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 0,
                'released' => 0,
            ]);

        $products = (new ProductSearcher)->getPrintedProducts(true);

        $this->assertCount(2, $products);

        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->first()->is($firstProduct),
            'The first product is not the expected one.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->first()->productVersion->is($firstProduct->productVersion),
            'The first product does not have the expected Product Version associated.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->first()->productVersion->tag->is($firstProduct->productVersion->tag),
            'The first product does not have the expected Tag associated.'
        );

        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->last()->is($secondProduct),
            'The last product is not the expected one.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->last()->productVersion->is($secondProduct->productVersion),
            'The last product does not have the expected Product Version associated.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->last()->productVersion->tag->is($secondProduct->productVersion->tag),
            'The last product does not have the expected Tag associated.'
        );
    }

    public function test_correct_products_get_returned_when_released_only_is_false(): void
    {
        $firstProduct = Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 1,
                'released' => 0,
            ]);

        $secondProduct = Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 1,
                'released' => 0,
            ]);

        Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 1,
                'released' => 1,
            ]);

        Product::factory()
            ->has(
                ProductVersion::factory()
                    ->has(Tag::factory())
            )
            ->create([
                'printed' => 0,
                'released' => 1,
            ]);

        $products = (new ProductSearcher)->getPrintedProducts(true);

        $this->assertCount(2, $products);

        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->first()->is($firstProduct),
            'The first product is not the expected one.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->first()->productVersion->is($firstProduct->productVersion),
            'The first product does not have the expected Product Version associated.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->first()->productVersion->tag->is($firstProduct->productVersion->tag),
            'The first product does not have the expected Tag associated to the Product Version.'
        );

        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->last()->is($secondProduct),
            'The last product is not the expected one.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->last()->productVersion->is($secondProduct->productVersion),
            'The last product does not have the expected Product Version associated.'
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $products->last()->productVersion->tag->is($secondProduct->productVersion->tag),
            'The last product does not have the expected Tag associated to the Product Version.'
        );
    }
}
```

Let me explain:

1. We have 2 tests, because the only parameters variation we have for `ProductSearcher` is either `true` or `false`.

   - So, for the first test we create models that have `released = 1`, but we also create some that have `released = 0` so we make sure those are not being got too. We also create at least one with `released = 0` so we are also not getting that one.
   - For the second test, same thing but inverse (only invert `released`). We want to make sure we are getting all that has `printed = 1` but `released = 0`.
2. We do not need to create 4 tests with these models variations, because we depend on the method argument, not the models properties:

   - We only depend on `$releasedOnly = true` -> Model: `printed = 1, released = 1`.
   - `$releasedOnly = false` -> Model: `printed = 1, released = 0`.
   - We added others with different variations to make sure our filters are working as expected.
3. I am also checking that we are getting the desired models, and not only that, I am also checking we are getting the expected relations, I am making sure I am getting exactly what I would expect. That is why I have created `ProductVersion` and `Tag` models related to each other as we would expect.
4. **NEVER EVER** test more than one thing at a time in the same test (we are testing more than one thing, but I am referring to the actual code, not if the model has 20 desired properties). You must always test exactly what you are trying to assert/check. You will see an answer that is creating everything and testing both variations, that is not desired, as for you to make sure you are getting what you expect you have to write giant asserts testing everything, we done so but in 2 different tests, it is more readable (but in this case longer) but you can make sure you got bot you expected 100%.

Comment: It seems that factory is only used to create a model object? How do I test method like `Product::get()`? (Or slightly more complicated function like the one I have given in the question?)

Comment: You don't test `get` or `with`, etc. That is core code, you don't test core code because it works. What you should have is a model with `printed = true` and another one with it been `false`, and test it gives back the desired model. Then the same with `released`. But you are testing the framework, you never test the framework, you test your own code and logic.

Comment: You are correct that major thing I want to test is with the logic of `printed`. So, may I have an example on how should I test `getPrintedProducts()`? Or do I need to refactor the function in other to have it tested?

Comment: Updated, let me know if this helps better now, ask me anything you don't understand please

Answer (score 2):

Best way, imo, to test that kind of functionality is setting a test database in memory. Then, when it's empyt, creating during test couple of models using factories. Then you known how much of database records you have and what kind. Then just check if class returns right ones.

Second way is using IoC - refactor ProductSearcher and pass Product model class as dependency. Then you can easily mock class during tests.

But i have another question - why you created ProductSearcher class in the first place? Wouldn't be easier to use scope instead?

If you wanted to use factories this is how to do that:

- First - define factory. For main model and its relationships if needed. For convenience you can use states to create predefined sets of values in records. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories
- Second - create a test. My example:

  ```
    public function testChossingCorrectingProductFromProductVersionIds()  
   {  
    $productSearcher= new ProductSearcher(); 

    $notPrinted = Product::factory->count(2)->create([  
        'printed' => false,  
        'released' => false  
    ]);  

    $printed = Product::factory->count(3)->create([  
        'printed' => true,  
        'released' => false  
    ]);   

    $releasedNotPrinted = Product::factory->count(4)->create([  
        'printed' => false,  
        'released' => true  
    ]);

    $releasedPrinted = Product::factory->count(5)->create([  
        'printed' => true,  
        'released' => true  
    ]);  

    $this->assertCount(8, $productSearcher->getPrintedProducts( false ) );  
    $this->assertCount(5, $productSearcher->getPrintedProducts( true ));
  ```

  }

Some developers are over sensitive about "one test, one assert", but i'm not one of them, as you can see  :D

Comment: Good answer, but related to the "some developer are over-sensitive about one test one assert", we are not over-sensitive... a test **ONLY** tests one thing, why ? Because if the first assertion fails, the second one related to other stuff will never be tested until you fix the previous one, so you could have 2 failing tests instead of 1... Also, you may be setting data that should not be set, in your case you are creating stuff that you should not have. Remember, tests should only have the minimum data setup to be in the same context as the real case... you are "over" creating... that's a nono

Comment: As general rule of thumb i fully agree. My solution is just short and uncomplicated - that's all. I'm aware it may (someone may even says "should") be written as separate tests, as you presented it in your answer. Writing "some developer are over-sensitive about one test one assert" i thought about literally one assert statement in test, what is, imho, unrealistic. BTW - i think you're solution is better :)